# Add custom rules for parsing quarters to SUTime

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, sutime

I'm following [the official instructions](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/sutime.html#example-1-fiscal-year) for adding custom SUTime rules for fiscal year quarters (stuff like Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4).

I used the default `defs.sutime.txt` and `english.sutime.txt` as templates for my own rule files.

After appending the following code to my `defs.sutime.txt`

```
  // Financial Quarters
  FYQ1 = {
      type: QUARTER_OF_YEAR,
      label: "FYQ1",
      value: TimeWithRange(TimeRange(IsoDate(ANY,10,1), IsoDate(ANY,12,31), QUARTER))
  }
  FYQ2 = {
      type: QUARTER_OF_YEAR,
      label: "FYQ2",
      value: TimeWithRange(TimeRange(IsoDate(ANY,1,1), IsoDate(ANY,3,31), QUARTER))
  }
  FYQ3 = {
      type: QUARTER_OF_YEAR,
      label: "FYQ3",
      value: TimeWithRange(TimeRange(IsoDate(ANY,4,1), IsoDate(ANY,6,30), QUARTER))
  }
  FYQ4 = {
      type: QUARTER_OF_YEAR,
      label: "FYQ4",
      value: TimeWithRange(TimeRange(IsoDate(ANY,7,1), IsoDate(ANY,9,30), QUARTER))
  }
```

and appending the following code to my `english.sutime.txt`

```
  # Financial Quarters
  FISCAL_YEAR_QUARTER_MAP = {
    "Q1": FYQ1,
    "Q2": FYQ2,
    "Q3": FYQ3,
    "Q4": FYQ4
  }
  FISCAL_YEAR_QUARTER_YEAR_OFFSETS_MAP = {
    "Q1": 1,
    "Q2": 0,
    "Q3": 0,
    "Q4": 0
  }
  $FiscalYearQuarterTerm = CreateRegex(Keys(FISCAL_YEAR_QUARTER_MAP))

  {
    matchWithResults: TRUE,
    pattern: ((/$FiscalYearQuarterTerm/) (FY)? (/(FY)?([0-9]{4})/)),
    result:  TemporalCompose(INTERSECT, IsoDate(Subtract({type: "NUMBER", value: $$3.matchResults[0].word.group(2)}, FISCAL_YEAR_QUARTER_YEAR_OFFSETS_MAP[$1[0].word]), ANY, ANY), FISCAL_YEAR_QUARTER_MAP[$1[0].word])
  }

  {
    pattern: ((/$FiscalYearQuarterTerm/)),
    result: FISCAL_YEAR_QUARTER_MAP[$1[0].word]
  }
```

I'm still unable to correctly parse stuff like "Q1 2020".

How can I properly add rules for parsing fiscal year quarters (e.g. "Q1")?

Here's my full code:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.time.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;

public class SUTimeSoExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("sutime.includeRange", "true");
        props.setProperty("sutime.markTimeRanges", "true");
        props.setProperty("sutime.rules", "./defs.sutime.txt,./english.sutime.txt");

        AnnotationPipeline pipeline = new AnnotationPipeline();
        pipeline.addAnnotator(new TokenizerAnnotator(false));
        pipeline.addAnnotator(new WordsToSentencesAnnotator(false));
        pipeline.addAnnotator(new POSTaggerAnnotator(false));
        pipeline.addAnnotator(new TimeAnnotator("sutime", props));

        String input = "Stuff for Q1 2020";

        Annotation annotation = new Annotation(input);
        annotation.set(CoreAnnotations.DocDateAnnotation.class, "2020-06-01");
        pipeline.annotate(annotation);
        System.out.println(annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation.class));
        List<CoreMap> timexAnnsAll = annotation.get(TimeAnnotations.TimexAnnotations.class);
        for (CoreMap cm : timexAnnsAll) {
            System.out.println(cm // match
                    + " --> " + cm.get(TimeExpression.Annotation.class).getTemporal() // parsed value
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I deleted the deafult `defs.sutime.txt` and `english.sutime.txt` files from the stanford corenlp models JAR in order to avoid [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970286/configuring-sutime-to-use-custom-rule-files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Java code example here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/sutime.html

It should work if you follow that example, mainly building your pipeline in this manner:

```
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner");
props.setProperty("ner.docDate.usePresent", "true");
// this will shut off the statistical models if you only want to run SUTime only
props.setProperty("ner.rulesOnly", "true");
// add your sutime properties as in your example
...
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

and make sure to use version 4.0.0.

You can set `ner.rulesOnly` to true if you just want to run SUTime without running the statistical models.

You can use one of several properties for `ner.docDate` or just set the document date in the annotation before running.

Comment: Note, if you set the ner.docDate.usePresent, it will overwrite the docDate your code directly sets, so don't do both.

Comment: Thank you. Upgrading to 4.0.0 fixed my issue. I didn't even need to provide a custom `defs.sutime.txt` and `english.sutime.txt` since the default files in 4.0.0 already contain rules for parsing fiscal year quarters.